# Saving changes in resource files with LINQ to XML in .net

Tags: vb.net, resources, linq-to-xml

I am working with .net resources using LINQ to XML. I want to edit some resources, so I coded this:

```
    Public Shared Sub AddTranslation(ByVal filename As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
    Dim items = From translation In XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data") Where translation.Attribute("name").Value = name
    If items.Count = 0 Then 'item doesn't exist => add new item
        XElement.Load(filename).Element("translations").Add(New XElement("data", New XAttribute("name", name), New XElement("value", value)))
    Else
        items(0).Element("value").Value = value
        XElement.Load(filename).Save(filename)
    End If
End Sub
```

This seems to work, and even when I debug VisualStudio says that the file changed, but actually it doesn't. I think the problem is in the Save() action, but I don't know other way to save it...
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Alf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simply load and store in a variable, then manipulate, then store back, along the following lines:

```
Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(filename)
Dim items = From translation In root.Elements("data") Where translation.Attribute("name").Value = name
If Not(items.Any) Then 'item doesn't exist => add new item
    root.Add(New XElement("data", New XAttribute("name", name), New XElement("value", value)))
Else
    items(0).Element("value").Value = value
End If
root.Save(filename)
```

That should give you an idea on how to approach that.